# Calculating total number of rows for an IR from Page 0

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a number of different Interactive Reports within my application (using Oracle ApEx 4.1), on different pages.

On each of these reports, I have pagination but I have been asked to also provide on each of the reports, the overall total number of records, displayed somewhere on the page per report.

Is there a means of doing this functionality on Page 0 or do I need to calculate total records for each report separately?

### Update for commenter

As mentioned in my previous comment, I added the new "**p_use_filter**" boolean parameter and set this to FALSE and all works fine.

I have another query. On one of the IR reports, within my where condition, I am using a bind variable but when I drill down on a report field that passes to the other report with the bind variable a STRING and then look at the backend SQL statement, I am getting an INVALID RELATIONAL OPERATOR error because the SQL has a WHERE condition like:

```
WHERE (CUSTOMER_NAME = ABC AIRLINES LTD )
```

i.e. it is trying to parse the SQL without single quotes around **ABC AIRLINES LTD** ?

Comment: In apex 4.2 there is a package APEX_IR with which you can retrieve an IR report sql. I made an own package which works in 4.1 and can return the IR sql fine. If you're interested in that i'll try to get it on github or somesuch.

Comment: Tom - that would be great but could this be used to determine the overall total of number of records as I basically need a select count(*)  with the from and where clauses of each IR queries. Tom, if your package can accommodate this requirement then would definitely like to have a look. Github link would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I'd simply retrieve the ir sql, and wrap it as a subselect in a `select count(*)`. I'll have a link up later today as i have no access to git any sooner.

Comment: Thanks Tom - whatever is easiest. Will check back later on.

Comment: So actually (and i only just thought about this), is a pagination scheme which displayed the total amount of records not sufficient? (Row Ranges X to Y of Z)

Comment: Hi Tom, I actually am using this pagination scheme but unfortunately the users are not happy with this approach. They actually want the overall total count of rows. I'm still working through your solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd propose to retrieve the IR SQL and then execute that SQL wrapped in a `SELECT COUNT(*) from (...)`.

Now, with Apex 4.2 you get the apex_ir package which can get the report SQL, but in pre 4.2 you do not have such a package. I have made one for myself, and I've used it for several things ([I've blogged a bit about these](http://tpetrus.blogspot.be/2012/03/record-navigation-plugged-in.html) for example).

The code needs some cleaning, but it is functional and has plenty of commentary in it. It'll parse all the filters and transform them into SQL again. It does not handle computations or GROUP BYs.  It'll maybe have some kinks left in the cable somewhere, but it may depend on what you want to do with it. In this case it shouldn't be a problem.

[Git link](https://github.com/tompetrus/oracle-apex-ir-pkg.git)

Basically, install the package in your schema, and then use code like this to run it:

```
DECLARE
   lNullTable  DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2_TABLE;
   lDebug      VARCHAR2(4000);
   lSql        VARCHAR2(4000);
   lCount      NUMBER;
BEGIN
   lSql := apex_ir_pkg.get_ir_sql
      (
         p_app_id             => :APP_ID,
         p_session_id         => :APP_SESSION,
         p_page_id            => :APP_PAGE_ID,
         p_report_id          => NULL,
         p_app_user           => :APP_USER,
         p_use_session_state  => TRUE,
         p_binds              => lNullTable,
         p_binds_val          => lNullTable,
         p_incl_order_by      => FALSE,
         p_debug              => lDebug,
      );
   
   lSql := 'SELECT count(*) FROM ('||lSql||')';
   
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lSql INTO lCount;
END;
```

Comment: Hi Tom, all works fine but how can I make your routine always return the total amount of records and ignore any filtering performed on an IR report? Basically always want total count and disregard any filtered records. Thanks.

Comment: Oh okay. You basically want to execute the SQL defined for the report? If so, does it have bind variables in it (page items) or is it plain sql?

Comment: Hi Tom, some IRs have bind variables and some don't. I basically always want to ignore any filtering performed by the user alone but always return total count of records. Thanks.

Comment: Best then that you comment everything between line 1231 and 1396: this is the processing of the search and filter conditions. There is no input parameter to disable those, so either do that or comment the lines for now.

Comment: Thanks for the info again Tom. I will add a new parameter "p_use_fiter" to your code to cater for the processing of the search and filter conditions. Pls let me know if you would like me to fork your code with this new change after I have tested it.

Comment: Hi Tom, as mentioned in my previous comment to you, I added the new "p_use_filter" boolean parameter and set this to FALSE and all works fine, so thanks for that. Pls see above in my original question for a query I have for you, too long to write within this comment - thanks.

Comment: Pfew, odd. Looks like it might be a bug to be honest. In the code there is this line `lv_combined := regexp_replace(lv_combined, UPPER(lv_binds(i)), NVL(v(LTRIM(UPPER(lv_binds(i)), ':')), 'NULL'), 1, 0, 'i');`. Try replacing the third argument with `''''||NVL(v(LTRIM(UPPER(lv_binds(i)), ':'))||''''`. It looks pretty obivous, i may not have run into this or i just picked an older version of my code (dang)

Comment: by the way: I'll add the filter parameter in the code by tomorrow, and i'll test the bind vars aswell

Comment: Thanks Tom - I'll wait to hear back from you with updated changes and hopefully download your updated package from your Git link.

Comment: @tonsils I commited some changes to the code including the parameter and a fix for the bind variable values. I have not stumbled on them because so far i've only had to use numbers (IDs). Good catch.

Comment: No probs Tom. All good. Once again, thanks for your help on this Tom.

Answer (score 0):

You can use #TOTAL_ROWS# in the header or footer of the region, but it will only show the initial value. i use it for classic reports. I don't think it plays well with the IR javascript. That's a partial page refresh.
See: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2239712 and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21674/ui_region.htm#CHDBCGJH

Comment: Hi, #TOTAL_ROWS# just returns me the rows based on pagination rows, in my case 15 rows and not the overall total of all the rows in my report, for example 200 rows in total - any ideas? Thanks.